# How to send a caught exception with NewRelic?

Tags: android, exception, newrelic

I can't find a sample code online on how to send **caught exceptions** to NewRelic on Android. I just want something like:

```
try{
...
}catch(final Exception e){

    NewRelic.sendException(e);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: As @karlpcrowley says, the call doesn't exist. but, you can use the mParticle SDK which does have that type of call, and then enable new relic on the server side, and mParticle will send your stack traces/exceptions to the appropriate API. full disclosure - i work for mParticle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately a call like this doesn't exist in the mobile SDK but I've logged a feature request for this.
Thanks for the suggestion!